# JNI on Android: How to retrieve a string from Java code?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I read a lot of examples to retrieve a java string in C/C++ code, but it seems that I miss something. this simple code doesn't work..

In ActivityTest  (android java code) I've:

```
public static native void nativeInit(String stringfromjava);
```

In TestActivity I've:

```
ActivityTest.nativeInit("test");
```

and in my test-jni.c:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL  Java_com_test_jni_ActivityTest_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject obj, jstring stringfromjava){

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TESTJNI","Native Init started");

const char* w_buf = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, stringfromjava, 0);

if(w_buf == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TESTJNI","file path recv nothing");
}

else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TESTJNI","String: %s", w_buf);
}

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, stringfromjava, w_buf);

}
```

But in my logcat I get only:

```
I/TESTJNI (18921): Native Init started
I/TESTJNI (18921): String:
```

Where I'm wrong...?

**FIXED**
Thanks to Mario, removing "jobject obj" from the signature fixed my issue!

Comment: If Mario's answer fixed the problem for you, you should mark his answer as accepted (click the tick next to his answer).

Comment: Did you add a static block in Java like this: `static {
        nativeInit();
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only wrote one short test so far (similar to your program), but my function had a bit different signature (might depend on SDK/NDK/JDK version? took it from some tutorial code I found):

```
extern "C" void Java_com_whatever_Activity_method(JNIEnv* env, jobject jthis, jstring param);
```

Obviously you won't need `extern "C"` if you're not writing C++.

The Java signature would be:

```
native void method(String param);
```

Edit:

To obtain the string (not sure if this is 100% correct, but it works):

```
const char *cparam = env->GetStringUTFChars(param, 0);
// .. do something with it
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(param, cparam);
```

Open to suggestions in case there's something wrong in there. It works fine, but might still be some issue, so feel free to comment.

Comment: that's the same thing the OP did.

Comment: @ethan: It's not. I'm skipping the `jclass` in the parameter list as well as `JNIEnv` in the string functions.

Comment: i was having the exact same problem. Thank you!